# Nested models in Django serializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I wish to receive JSON formatted like that:

```
{
    detailing: [
        <detailing>,
        ...
    ],
    results: [
        {
            id: <id>,
            data: [
                {
                    x: <tag>,
                    y: <count>
                },
                ...
            ]
            summ: <summary count>,
            percentage: <percentage summary count>
        },
        {
            id: <id>,
            data: [
                {
                    x: <tag>,
                    y: <count>
                },
                ...
            ]
            summ: <summary count>,
            percentage: <percentage summary count>
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

In other words, i need 'detailing'(not for every 'Floor' instance, but for all) field above the 'results' field, and 'results' have to contains all of 'Floor' instances. I think, that for this problem solving, i need 3 serializers classes, one for 'detailing', one for 'results' and one for aggregate it together.

Here is my code sample:

```
#  serializers.py
class DetailingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    detailing = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('detailing',)

    def get_detailing(self, obj):
        return ['dekaminute', 'hour', 'day']

class FloorTrackPointsCountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    results = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Floor
        fields = ('results','detailing',)

    def get_results(self, obj):
        res = [
            {
                'id': obj.id,
                'data': [{'tag':tp.tag,'timestamp':tp.created_at} for tp in obj.trackpoint_set.all()],
                'summ': obj.trackpoint_set.values('tag').distinct().count(),
                'percentage': 0.5
            }

        ]
        return res

class AggregationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    detailing = DetailingSerializer(many=True)
    results = FloorTrackPointsCountSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('results', 'detailing')


#  view.py
class FloorTrackPointsCountViewSet(ListForGraphicViewSet):
    queryset = Floor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AggregationSerializer

#  models.py
class Floor(InModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=False, blank=True)
    number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['number']

class TrackPoint(VirtualDestroyModel):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    floor = models.ForeignKey(Floor)
    x                       = models.FloatField(default=0, null=False, blank=False)
    y                       = models.FloatField(default=0, null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag
```

And now, all i have is Traceback

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `detailing` on serializer `AggregationSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Floor` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Floor' object has no attribute 'detailing'.
```

What is my mistake and is this approach justified?
Best Regards.